# JKS KeyStore not available

Tags: java, android

I'm providing the keystore path but it returns exception android.system.errnoexception open failed eacces (permission denied).
I've also given the read and write permissions and used android:requestLegacyExternalStorage="true".

```
public static String generateSignature(String data) throws Exception {

   String jksFilepath = "/storage/emulated/0/key/KeyDemoo.jks";

        File file=new File(jksFilepath);
        try {
          
            Log.e("TAG", "generateSignature:try ");

            Log.e("TAG", "generateSignature: "+file.getPath());

            InputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream(file.getPath());

            // Loading Keystore
            // System.out.println("loading keystore");
            ks.load(fileInputStream, JKSPassword);
            Enumeration<String> e = ks.aliases();

            while (e.hasMoreElements()) {
                alias = e.nextElement();
                // System.out.println("Alias of the e-Token : "+ alias);

                UserCert = (X509Certificate) ks.getCertificate(alias);

                UserCertPubKey = (PublicKey) ks.getCertificate(alias).getPublicKey();

                // System.out.println("loading Private key");
                UserCertPrivKey = (PrivateKey) ks.getKey(alias, JKSPassword);
            }

            // Method Call to generate Signature
            signature = MakeSignature(data);

            return signature;

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
            System.out.println("generateSignature" + e.getCause());
            throw new Exception();
        }

}
```

Comment: `/Users/narinderbansal/KeyDemoo.jks` looks like a path on your local machine, but your tag and the `Log.e` call tell me that this is meant to run on Android: of course an Android device (even an emulated one) doesn't have access to files on your local machine. You need to bundle the files you want to access into your Android application (probably as a resource).

Comment: @JoachimSauer i've tried the path from my android device too but it keeps giving me the same exception.

Comment: @JoachimSauer when i comment the lines  
Security.addProvider(new BouncyCastleProvider());
ks = KeyStore.getInstance("jks");

it gives me android.system.errnoexception open failed eacces (permission denied) this exception

Comment: If you have updatest to your question, please [edit] your question with the exact code you tried and the results you got. Just *describing* the attempts is not sufficient without actual code. And the comments are not well-suited for detailed explanations.

Comment: @JoachimSauer done sir please check.

Comment: You need to [read up on Android 11 storage changes](https://developer.android.com/about/versions/11/privacy/storage). You can't just go read random paths in recent Android versions, you can only get to some specific paths. That's why I suggested bundling the key into your app. If you insist on storing as a file then you must either put it into an accessible place or make the user pick the file for you to read.